# Programmatically open multiple windows as byobu windows

Tags: bash, byobu

I need to execute several bash scripts in background with a screen devoted to each script within byobu session.

So how to invoke a byobu window for each script like:

```
$byobu-multiple script1.bash script2.bash ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern byobu is based on tmux, so you can simply use the `tmux new-window` command.

You can do one for each command:

```
tmux new-window script1.bash
tmux new-window script2.bash
```

If you really need a one-liner you could use xargs:

```
echo script1.bash script2.bash | xargs --max-args=1 tmux new-window
```

If you have multiple byobu sessions running in parallel, you can run `tmux list-sessions` to see them, and could append the `tmux new-window` command with `-t` to point it at a specific session.